# Cannot read property 'getContext' of null even after putting canvas before script

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

All I want to do is start using the canvas but I continue to get this error. I have seen many people telling others to put the canvas tags before the script tags and I have done this and it hasn't fixed the problem.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cross Stats Graph</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas> id="chart" width="720" height="720"</canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
```

Comment: The tag should be `<canvas id="chart" width="720" height="720"></canvas>`. You have put the attributes outside of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're id is not in the html tag

`<canvas id="chart" width="720" height="720"></canvas>`

Should fix your problem

Comment: Thanks so much new to programming and the help fixing my stupid mistakes is really appreciated.

Comment: Happens all the time to everyone no matter the skill level :D